# Programming penalized smoothing on R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm currently learning FDA (functional data analysis), following "Introduction to Functional Data Analysis" by Kokoszka & Reimherr. I'm trying to understand section 2.2 and how to program penalized smoothing in general, for example the exercice **2.2**, part **(b)** specifically:

> **2.2** Download the R package fds and use the data set FedYieldcurve,
> which contains the monthly Federal Reserve interest rates, cf. *Problem 1.2*.
>
> **(a)** Smooth the interest rates (yields) in January 1982 using a B–spline
> basis with four basis functions. Plot the raw and smoothed interest rates on
> one graph.
>
> **(b)** Re–fit the January 1982 yields using a penalized smoothing based on six
> basis functions (as many as data points) with with the smoothing parameter
> λ = 1, and the second derivative as the penalty operator. Add the smooth in
> red to the graph you obtained in part *(a)* and comment on the result.
>
> **(c)** Repeat part *(b)* with several other smoothing parameters λ. Which λ
> gives the most informative smooth curve?

This is my code by now:

```
##Exercice 2
#a)
library(fds); library(fda)
yield = FedYieldcurve; terms = yield$x
Y<-matrix(unlist(yield$y),nrow=6,ncol=330)[,1]
Y
View(Y)
B4.basis=create.bspline.basis(rangeval=c(1,120), nbasis=4)
Y.fd=smooth.basis(argvals=c(3,6,12,60,84,120),y=Y, fdParobj=B4.basis)
plot(Y.fd, ylab="", xlab="",col="gray",lty=1)
lines(c(3,6,12,60,84,120),Y)

#b)
pen_fit <- create.bspline.basis(c(0,120), nbasis = 6)
lambda <- 1
Lfd <- fdPar(pen_fit, Lfdobj = int2Lfd(2))
pen_smoothed <- smooth.basis(terms, Y, pen_fit, lambda, fdParobj = Lfd)
plot(pen_smoothed)
```

But it simply plots the same shape, and changing the value of lambda does basically nothing.